# How can I bind multiple gridviews to a single eventhandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a couple of ASP gridviews that, when I click on an index value, I save their associated ID. Instead of creating multiple eventhandlers for eachone I would like to bind them all into one single event handler.
Here is my asp code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvHighPriority" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grv_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"/>

<asp:GridView ID="grvMediumPriority" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grv_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"/>
```

And my C# code:

```
protected void grv_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String groupedErrorID = "";
    GridViewRow row = grvHighPriority.SelectedRow;
    groupedErrorID = row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
    lblID.Text = groupedErrorID; //for testing purposes
}
```

At the moment the eventhandler only works for the highestpriority gridview, but I would like to bind all of my gridviews to the same eventhandler. Is this possible? 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Found a working solution thanks to @Enrique:

```
protected void grv_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    **GridView r = (GridView)sender;**
    String groupedErrorID = "";
    **GridViewRow row = r.SelectedRow;**
    groupedErrorID = row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
    lblLogin.Text = groupedErrorID; //for testing purposes
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
    protected void grv_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String groupedErrorID = "";
            GridViewRow row = (((YourControl)sender).Parent.Parent as GridViewRow);        
            groupedErrorID = row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            lblID.Text = groupedErrorID; //for testing purposes
        }
```

`YourControl` could be like a LinkButton, Button, etc

Comment: Thank you, I found the solution!